# Disable retina display?

Tags: ios4, retina-display

I'm making an app but I don't wish to support retina display. The bad thing is that my app looks all pixelated. It's possible to deactivate  the retina display feature ? So that my texture's proportions won't be doubled.

The scale property of UIScreen is read only and it's value is 2.0 in iphone 4, I would like it to be 1.0, so that my graphics in the iphone 4 looks exactly the same as older devices, without pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale property of UIScreen is telling you that there are physically twice as many pixels in each direction on the retina screen.

You should not need to do anything special to get the app to appear the same on the retina display.

It will look slightly better if you provide @2x images though, and it may look more pixelated next to apps that are running at full resolution on the same device if the @2x images are not present.